# Replace spaces with zeroes in pipe-delimited file

Tags: regex, csv

I need to replace text in a file with following format. Can anyone provide me some idea?

Input: `|2|4|5| |6|7| | | |`

Output: `|2|4|5|0|6|7|0|0|0|`

Comment: @LukasEder: You should undelete your post. I've edited it slightly, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you're using but for PHP it could be something like

```
$str = '|2|4|5| |6|7| | | |';
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\|)\s+(?=\|)/','0',$str);
```